# ORA-19100: PASSING or RETURNING keyword expected

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery

I have a simple table with XML data

```
create table emp
(dept xmltype)
```

And the data in it

```
insert into emp values ('<dept bldg="101">
<employee id="901">
    <name>
        <first>John</first>
        <last>Doe</last>
    </name>
    <office>344</office>
    <salary currency="USD">55000</salary>
</employee>
</dept>')


insert into emp values ('<dept bldg="103">
<employee id="902">
    <name>
        <first>Peter</first>
        <last>Pan</last>
    </name>
    <office>216</office>
    <phone>905-416-5004</phone>
    </employee>
</dept>')



insert into emp values ('<dept bldg="114">
<employee id="903">
    <name>
        <first>Mary</first>
        <last>Jones</last>
    </name>
    <office>415</office>
    <phone>905-403-6112</phone>
    <phone>647-504-4546</phone>
    <salary currency="USD">64000</salary>
</employee>
</dept>')
```

And when I do below, it throws ORA-19100: PASSING or RETURNING keyword expected

```
select XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$INPT_XML/dept/employee/office/text()' PASSING dept  
AS "INPT_XML") AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM emp;
```

Could anyone assist me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing, but your error tells you what's wrong, you need the RETURNING CONTENT clause.

```
SELECT
XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$INPT_XML/dept/employee/office/text()' PASSING dept AS "INPT_XML" RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(20) )
```

FROM
    emp;

Gives me back this output:

```
XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$I
--------------------
344
216
415
```

Good info, how-to's on Oracle XML [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-features/xmldb/overview/xmldb-bpwp-12cr1-1964809.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in missed RETURNING CONTENT clause.

It seems that Oracle forces to use it.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions236.htm#SQLRF06209

RETURNING CONTENT indicates that the result from the XQuery evaluation is either an XML 1.0 document or a document fragment conforming to the XML 1.0 semantics.